# Google sheets returns random versions of a published document

Tags: google-sheets

Google sheets allows everyone reading published documents as CSV. I edited a document then I execute the following CLI command repeatedly and I get different content (document versions) each time. Only after 5+ minutes it starts producing actual content stably.

Q: Is there a way to retrieve actual information by that link rather than random?

```
# the curl command is like this
# the URL is picked from the "publish to the web" UI dialog
curl "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/SOME_COMPLEX_ID/pub?output=csv"
```

Background: wanted to try the Sheets as a tiny DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that using queries we can avoid that (caching?) randomness. This solves the problem + the changes are applied immediately.

```
curl "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_ID/gviz/tq?gid=0&tqx=out:csv&tq=select%20A,B,C,D"
```